# javascript function is not defined for td tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```html
<td valign="top">null
<script type="text/javascript">
function viewStack1355381490(){
        var StackWindow = window.open("about:blank", "", "toolbar=0,width=800,height=400,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes");
        StackWindow.document.write("<HTML><HEAD>");
        StackWindow.document.write("<LINK rel=stylesheet href=/oss.css>");
 StackWindow.document.write("<TITLE>Stack Trace</TITLE>");
 StackWindow.document.write("</HEAD><BODY>");
 StackWindow.document.write("<PRE>");
 StackWindow.document.write("blablabla");
 StackWindow.document.write("</PRE>");
 StackWindow.document.write("<br/><br/><b><a href='' onClick='self.close()'>Close Window</a></b><p>");
 StackWindow.document.write("</BODY></HTML>");
}
</script>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:viewStack1355381490()">[<u><b>Exception</b></u>]</a>
</td>
```

When I click on Exception link I get this error: `viewStack1355381490 is not defined`. Could you please help me find the cause?

Comment: You don't get that error. It says *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null"*. Since you are trying to read that property within the function, the function as to have been defined.

Comment: i get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined` becuase StackWindow is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define your `StackWindow` which should be

```
var StackWindow;
```

working one as follows:

```html
<td valign="top">null<script type="text/javascript">function viewStack1355381490(){
        var StackWindow;
        StackWindow = window.open("about:blank", "", "toolbar=0,width=800,height=400,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes");
        StackWindow.document.write("<HTML><HEAD>");
        StackWindow.document.write("<LINK rel=stylesheet href=/oss.css>");
        StackWindow.document.write("<TITLE>Stack Trace</TITLE>");
        StackWindow.document.write("</HEAD><BODY>");
        StackWindow.document.write("<PRE>");
        StackWindow.document.write("blablabla");
        StackWindow.document.write("</PRE>");
        StackWindow.document.write("<br/><br/><b><a href='' onClick='self.close()'>Close Window</a></b><p>");
        StackWindow.document.write("</BODY></HTML>");
}</script>
 <a href="javascript:viewStack1355381490()">[<u><b>Exception</b></u>]</a>
</td>
```

Moreover, you will get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

because `window.open` is not allowed in sandboxed frame without enabling allow-popups permissions, but it should work on direct document.

Comment: I added `var` to `StackWindow` declaration, but it didn't help. I still have this error in console

Comment: `VM603:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: viewStack1355381490 is not defined(…)`

Comment: I've tried it and it is working fine, is there any other code which comes between this script and link?